# d3js strange date and data handling

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I took the following example of d3js:

[d3.js Area Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195)

and just modified the data a bit. The relevant modified code is:

`var data = [
    {"date":"01-May-2000","close":"100"},
    {"date":"30-Apr-2012","close":"200"},
    {"date":"27-Apr-2012","close":"300"},
    {"date":"26-Apr-2012","close":"400"},
    {"date":"25-Apr-2012","close":"500"},
    {"date":"16-Mar-2012","close":"600"},
    {"date":"15-Mar-2012","close":"500"},
    {"date":"14-Mar-2012","close":"400"},
    {"date":"13-Mar-2012","close":"300"},
    {"date":"12-Mar-2012","close":"200"},
    {"date":"12-Mar-2012","close":"100"}
];
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%Y").parse;`

The difference of the first and the second timestamp is ~12 years. All other data points looks pressed. Is that a bug? Or what can I do that the last datapoints are not pressed at the end of the chart?

[Here is an example with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WCFfa/)

Cheers
Jonny

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. Note that evading the question edit error you were getting for not doing so is ridiculous.

Comment: you should also sort the `data` array by date first...

Answer (score 1):

they look pressed because the last entries are a relatively small timeframe compared to the 12 years, I think you could use a "non time-based" scale to show the data if you only care about the values in the dataset